# Can i configure validation in xxxx-validation.xml for List?

Tags: java, struts2

Now in my save action,i defined a model which called booking and it is as following:

```
Class BookingAction {
       private Booking booking;
       ...
}

Class Booking {
  private String bookingNo;
  private String status;
  ...
  private List<Part>parts = new ArrayList<Part>(); 
  ...
}

Class Part {
  private String partNo;
  ...
}
```

I also defined a validation xml file for that action,e.g

```
<validators>
    <field name="booking.status">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message>${getText("MandatoryFieldEmpty",{"%{getText(\"BookingMain.status\")}"})}</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>

    <field name="booking.bookedBy">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
        <message>${getText("MandatoryFieldEmpty",{"%{getText(\"BookingMain.bookedBy\")}"})}</message>
    </field-validator>
    </field>
....
```

Can I define this kinda of configuration for Part too?

The Part is in a List  and the List is Booking's property, does anybody could tell me if i could have Part's validation in BookingAction-validation.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Visitor Validator](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/visitor-validator.html);

You should add the `<validator type="visitor">` snippet related to `parts` object in your `BookingAction-validation.xml` to activate the Visitor validation;

Then, you'll need to create an `Part-validation.xml` **under the package of the `Part` Object** (instead of the package of the `Action` object), and specify there the rule for a single Part element.

`Struts2 Validation Interceptor` will take care of validating each element of the List by using this second file.

As a nice side effect, if you include a `List<Part>` object in another `Action`, your validation for `Part` object will be already there, with no need to rewrite it in another file (you will only need to declare the validator snippet in your Action-validation.xml file).

---

EDIT

You can specify different contexts for triggering a further, complementary validation of the same bean by using a more specific `Bean-context-validation.xml` file, only in some specific cases.

Read [**this detailed example**](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/validation-examples.html), especially the `Visitor Validation Example` (and the following `Visitor Validation with the Expression Validator`) part.

Comment: +1 for side effect. You can mention `context` parameter as well.